# Lucene search a content inside a file without indexing.

Tags: lucene

I am having a file inside an jdbc scrollable iterator where I am having limit to iterate. Now  I got a use case to search the file coming inside the iterator. So is there any way to pass a file and a search content to LUCENE to get the LUCENE HIT, without indexing and creating dir as given in LUCENE.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ***RAMDirectory*** instead of creating a physical directory on the filesystem. It will index for sure but the index will resides in the memory.  Also keep in mind it doesn't really shines for huge indexes. So depending on your application, it may or may not servers you well. Try it!

[RAMDirectory](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/store/RAMDirectory.html)

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am not happy to use RAMDirectory since it may impact the RAM memory. Is there any other search engine or in lucene itself, where a file and a content can be passed as parameter and to search.

Comment: I don't know. The index is the very heart of Lucene since it it an "Information Retrieval" library.

Comment: I don't want to retrieve information but just to know if it contains the text.